# OpenCV image analysis on 32x32 image sections?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to divide a passed in, 1920x1080, gray scaled image and divide it into 32x32 "blocks" or "sections". Sort of like an imaginary, overlay grid.

Once this is done, I need to loop through each pixel in each individual section to perform analysis on the single channel, gray scale value that is returned by each pixel.

For example:

```
//For block (x,y):

    if (pixelVal >= 120 && pixelVal <= 130) {
        bitStream += "1"; 
    } else if (pixelVal >= 135 && pixelVal <= 140) {
        bitstream += "0";
    } else {
        bitStream += "X";
    }
```

Does this make sense? I'm very new to OpenCV and C++ and basically I know how to show, loop through, and return the pixel value at a given point, just not within a certain, predetermined area. I asked a similar question the other day but it was for thresholding, not the single channel value. Im thinking about creating some sort of window that loops through and with each window, the pixel values within are compared using the conditionals I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value of gray scale pixels is already defined from `0-255`, so you may create an array of size 256 and pre-fill that array with `"0"`, `"1"` and `"x"` as per your conditions. This lookup table would later help you to substitute values very efficiently. This technique is used internally by OpenCV methods such as `cv::threshold`.

Then you may crop the image using `cv::Mat cropped = bigger_mat(rect)`, where `bigger_mat` is 1920x1080 dimension matrix and `rect` is `cv::Rect(x, y, w, h)` object which defined the position and size for cropping.

Then you can loop each of the cropped mats' using two nested `for` loops for rows and columns and access each pixel using `img.at<uchar>(j,i)`. For each value retrieved you can use the above created look-up array to get the substitution and append to your bitstream.

Comment: Thanks ZdaR! Im confused on the very first part of what you're saying. Im not sure why Im pre-filling an array with 0s, 1s, and Xs before anything is done. 
Let me explain a little further because I don't think Im being very clear:
1. Pass in image. Read it.
2. Divide image into 32x32 sections with (0,0) being the top left portion of the image.
3. Loop through each section to get the gray scale value of each pixel.
4. If pixel values are within set ranges, add 1s, 0s, or Xs to outputted bit stream.
Does that make more sense?

Comment: @CrowHop: He's suggesting you replace the if/elseif/else structure with a table lookup, which is much faster. You pre-compute the table at the start of the program, then use it within the inner loop to look up what to output for each pixel.

Comment: I get it. Ingenious! So basically I send the initial values every time before the program begins. Now for the "rect" function; the "(x,y)" in this case would be the i and j of the for loops as they would move through the image. W and H would be the 32x32....Im not too sure how that would work as the dimensions would probably cause some sort of memory issue.

Comment: you must try it and then post relevant code to get your problems solved.